# Django+React: Documentation review on an ongoing boilerplate project

Tags: django, reactjs, frontend, backend

I wrote a boilerplate project for my own `Django + React` integration design. I have a draft markdown file briefly documenting the project. If it's not too much to ask, maybe someone can help review it?

If the design is ideal for use, I will publish it on `Github` for free use, otherwise I will revise it based on your comments/suggestions.

Thanks!

Gist: https://gist.github.com/michaeljarizala/f0719ab7a56c5988a74ceb571805573c

Comment: This looks like a question that should be asked at: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm sorry I was actually just asking review on a markdown file's contents of a boilerplate project - whether the design idea expressed therein is ideal for the project to be used as Django-React project boilerplate.